# Can a pytest test change the value of a session fixture and affect subsequent tests?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Let's say that a pytest session fixture returns a dictionary and this dictionary is then manipulated within a test. Would this affect subsequent tests which use the same fixture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. And that is trivial to verify. Exactly one of these tests will fail:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def d():
    return {}

def test_one(d):
    assert not d
    d["k"] = "v"

def test_two(d):
    assert not d
    d["k"] = "v"
```

If the fixture scope is changed to "function" (the default scope) then both tests will pass, since the dict will be created anew each time.

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question: if a function-level fixture instantiates a class would a class attribute of that class exist after the test?

Comment: The class would live as long as it's referenced somewhere (same as any object). If you don't assign it to a surviving variable (e.g. a global variable or a class attribute), it will be garbage collected after the test.